# Django: Despite using full module path on import, the wrong Model is being referenced

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 django projects

- regalbeagle
- system_models

In each project, I have a "datasources" application:

- regalbeagle/datasources
- system_models/datasources

In each datasources application,

- regalbeagle/datasources/models.py
- system_models/datasources/models.py

I have a "Datasource" model:

```
 class Datasource(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField()
    source_type = SmallIntegerField(default=1)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.fullname
```

I will get into why I have two identical models in identically named applications in different projects in a second, but first I want to identify the odd behavior that I'm seeing.  I've installed the system_models project into the global python lib directory using python setup.py install.  However, when running python manage.py shell from within the regalbeagle project, I'm unable to access the Datasource model of system_models even when using the fully qualified path.

```
from system_models.datasources.models import Datasource as SystemDatasource
from regalbeagle.datasources.models import Datasource
```

When I use the python inspect module to see which file is being loaded, I'm seeing the following:

```
inspect.getfile(SystemDatasource)
'/Users/george/svn/regalbeagle/trunk/regalbeagle/../regalbeagle/datasources/models.pyc'

inspect.getfile(Datasource)
'/Users/george/svn/regalbeagle/trunk/regalbeagle/../regalbeagle/datasources/models.pyc'
```

However, if I create a dummy model within system_models of which there is no corresponding regalbeagle class, the path seems recognized:

```
from system_models.datasources.models import DummyClass
inspect.getfile(DummyClass)
'/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/system_models/datasources/models.pyc'
```

So my question is how does Django magically swap the Datasource class in system_models for the one in regalbeagle even though I imported using the full path?  If django doesn't like having two applications with the same name, why does my DummyClass seem to work ok?

The easiest fix seems to be to change the system_models model name to be SystemDatasource explicitly, but that seems to defeat the purpose of modules/packaging.

So my question is:

Is there some kind of additional information that I can specify so that Django will allow these to Models to co-exist?  Or am I SOL?

As promised, the explanation for why I need these two versions of Datasource:

I have a backend crawl process that needs to be able to write data into a database and for performance reasons I wanted this database separate from my web application.  So I created a systemdb and sync'd my system_models project against this.  My web application is able to view aggregated stats on the data that was crawled by the backend process and the information to do this is in the regalbeagle database.  There are some queries that require joining on a datasource table within regalbeagle and because there's no way to join across dbs, regalbeagle has its own copy of Datasource.  But I also need to be able to update information related to the crawl and I'm doing that through regalbeagle's admin interface.  Which means I need access to the system_models version of the table there as well.

Adding Full model definitions:

regalbeagle/datasources/models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class LanguageManager(models.Manager):
    def filter_by_datasources(self, exclude_datasource_id_list=None):
        qs = self.get_query_set().filter(datasource__isnull=False)
        if exclude_datasource_id_list:
            qs = qs.exclude(datasource__in=exclude_datasource_id_list)
        return qs.distinct()

class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    objects = LanguageManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = [ 'name' ]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "[%s] %s" % (self.id, self.name)

class DataSourceManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(DataSourceManager, self).get_query_set() \
            .extra(select={ 'lower_fullname': 'lower(fullname)' }) \
            .filter(is_inactive__isnull=True) \
            .order_by('lower_fullname')

class DataSource(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField()
    icon = models.URLField(null=True)
    language = models.ManyToManyField(Language, null=True)

    objects = DataSourceManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "[%s] %s, %s" % (self.id, self.fullname, self.url)

class DataSourceInactive(models.Model):
    datasource = models.OneToOneField(DataSource, null=True, related_name='is_inactive')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.datasource.__unicode__()
```

system_models/datasources/models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# DataSource -- these are the different places that we import data
# from.  
class DataSource(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField()
    source_type = SmallIntegerField(default=1)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.fullname
```

Comment: If you have made any recent structure / module changes try deleting all of your *.pyc files `find . -name '*.pyc' -delete`

Comment: Thanks Francis -- I tried that, deleted all *.pyc files from my regalbeagle project, and deleted the system_models from the global python repo and then reinstalled using python setup.py install.  Still observing the same behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Daniel.  I've attached the full model definitions -- I don't believe one is importing anything from the other.  That's why I had assumed there was some magic django thing happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Do you have any `import *`s anywhere?

Comment: In the system_models project there aren't any import *s.  In the regalbeagle project there are, but not in the datasources app.  When I run python manage.py shell how can I tell which model files are executed?  I thought it would only be settings.py -- and mine only imports sys and os.path.

Comment: Just in case, I've gone through and removed all import * s from everywhere in the reaglebeagle project.  I'm still seeing this behavior which is mucho frustrato...